# which command should i use on SQL for having?

Tags: sql

I want your help.
I have 2 columns with data, customer and city.
I want to show customers a mix if this customer has more different cities, and I want to show the customer if it has only 1 city.

for example, I have this data:

```
customer   city
ana        London    
Ella       London
Sarah      Paris
Haidi      Greece
Chloe      France
ana        London
Ella       france
```

I want to show it like this:

```
Ana     London
Ella    Mix
Sarah   Paris
Haidi   Greece
Chloe   France
```

How could I do this? Which command should I use?

Comment: You're not possibly using SQL Server, PostgreSQL and Azure SQL at the same time. Please [edit] your tags and use **ONLY** the tag that applies to the specific DBMS you're using. Tag spamming is a really good way to get downvoted and question closure here.

Comment: Greece and France aren't cities :)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

```
Select
Customer,
case when count(DISTINCT city) > 1 then 'MIX' Else max(City) End as City
from MyTable
Group by Customer
```

Comment: @cf_en, thanks for adding distinct in count. I missed it because the sample provided don't have a duplicate record, but good point.

Comment: you helped me so so much,,,,thank youuuuuuuuuuu

Answer (score 0):

You could use a command like before:

Select
Customer,
case when count(city) > 1 then 'MIX' Else City End as City
from Mytable
Group by Customer, City

but Ana is present twice in the table, and you have to use the Max to solve

Select
Customer,
case when count(city) > 1 then 'MIX' Else MAX(City) End as City
from Mytable
Group by Customer

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted `NULL` instead of `'Mix'`, you could use:

```
select customer, nullif(min(city), max(city)) as city
from t
group by customer;
```

You can actually extend this to get `'Mix'`:

```
select customer, coalesce(nullif(min(city), max(city)), 'Mix') as city
from t
group by customer;
```

But `NULL` makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think you're looking for

```
select customer, 
       case when count(*)>1
            then 'mix'
            else max(city) end as city
from t
group by customer;
```